# Laravel Livewire Hook not firing for a multiple images

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to upload images when the file field is updated but can't figure out why the UpdatedFoo method isn't fired,

```html
 <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" wire:model="photos"
                                       multiple>
                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose
                                    image {{ $key + 1 }}</label>
```

My Livewire component

```
    public $photos = [];



  public function UpdatedPhotos($value, $key)
  {
    $this->validate([
        'photos' => 'image|max:1024', // 1MB Max
    ]);

    $storage = new Storage(config('kizusi.client'));

    foreach ($this->photos as $photo) {
        $result = $storage->createFile('tours', 'unique()',  $photo);
        print_r($result);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got it,
The validation was preventing my images from being submitted

```
$this->validate([
        'photos' => 'image|max:1024', // 1MB Max
    ]);
```